# Lost on projection. Projective Geometrey.

Tags: geometry, projective-geometry

I was given this image, seen below, as a study guide,*I color coded it for ease of reading*, for the homework (which is to setup 3 perspectives that map $(a,b,c,d) \to (c,d,a,b)$). I am having trouble seeing the projectives.

$\color{red}{Q}\left(a,\color{red}{b^{\prime}},\color{red}{c^{\prime}},\color{red}{d^{\prime}}\right)\overset{d}{\doublebarwedge}\color{blue}{B}\left(b,\color{red}{b^{\prime}},\color{green}{c^{\prime\prime}},\color{yellow}{p}\right)\overset{\color{red}{c^{\prime}}}{\doublebarwedge}P\left(b,a,d,c\right)$

The ones that I don't understand are:

- How come $\color{red}{c^{\prime}} \to \color{green}{c^{\prime\prime}}$
- How does $\color{red}{b^{\prime}} \to a$
- How does $\color{green}{c^{\prime\prime}} \to d$
- How does $p \to c$

Please, (Yes, I understand that this was given to help with a homework problem) explain the projections.

**Mistake on graph, point $E$ should be $C^{\prime}$**
[image: several projectivites showing swapping of points]

Comment: I have troubles seeing it too. But probably it is easier to see if you pass to the dual picture. Replace lines by points, points by lines, lines intersecting at a point by points lying on a line, etc ...

Comment: I understand the property that lines and points can be swapped out with each other, but don't know exactly how to draw that.

Comment: Begin with the (former)lines. Place for each of them a (new)point in the plane and label them with the same names. Then, for each of these (new)points, representing the (former)lines, label the (new)line that passes through them using the name of the (former)point of intersection of the two (former)lines that are represented by those (new)points.

Comment: I am having a very difficult time trying to draw the dual, could you post a picture, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll demonstrate this in a single example.

> How come $c′\to c′′$?

You are performing a perspectivity between four lines through $Q$ and four lines trough $B$. You are using the points of intersection with line $d$ as the glue to identify them.

So $c'$ passes through $Q$, and it intersects $d$ in $E$. The line joining $E$ to $B$ is $c''$. This is why $c'$ gets mapped to $c''$.

The others should be the same.